# Collect temperature and fan speed with munin from Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, snmp, munin

I'm quite fond of [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) and using it also at home to monitor my PCs. What was super-duper easy under Linux is pretty much unsolvable for me under Windows: I'd like to monitor CPU and Motherboard temperatures as well as fan speed.

On Linux I'm using lm-sensors and the [plugin for munin was basically there](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/sensors_/details).

I access already some information from my Windows machine via SNMP (disk space, [CPU usage](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/snmp__cpu_usage/details), [memory usage](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/snmp_memory/details), [network](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/snmp__if_/details)); the graphs are simple as is the information exposed via SNMP, but they do their job.

But when it comes to temperature and fan speed I'm running against a wall. My research so far resulted in that Windows does not by default provide any out of the box ability to retrieve temperature/fan speed data. Third party applications are necessary which have knowledge how to communicate with the Motherboard chips.

The best I cam up with is that [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) exposes a shared memory interface and there exists a library which hooks into Windows SNMP facility and bridges over to SpeedFans shared memory interface; it's called [SFSNMP](http://deve.loping.net/projects/sfsnmp/). Unfortunately the library doesn't work, there's a [bug report at SpeedFan open](http://www.bugtrack.almico.com/view.php?id=1275) about it, but it's currently not moving (although the SFSNMP author is active there).

So, unless that's going to work like anytime soon, are there any alternatives? I'm not found of buying any software to get that feature, given that I take it as granted that my system exposes me the information to properly monitor it, but anyway don't just not answer because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of SFSNMP. First, the bug only appears when the processes SNMP.exe and SpeedFan.exe are running under different logins on >= Windows Vista. I already developed a small proxy library which reshares the SpeedFan SHM globally. I'm currently [ironing out the last bugs](http://deve.loping.net/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=12) from the CMake transition and in the new SHM proxy with the help of another forum user. I'm also creating a more reliable installer. I hope that I have it ready this week.

Comment: I'm the one participating in your discussion lately; funny how small the internet is :-)

Answer (score 1):

Speccy can monitor CPU temp, among other things. [Hmonitor](http://www.hmonitor.com/) is another option although I have never personally tested that one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will do everything you are looking for but [CPUID](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) is a pretty comprehensive app for monitoring your hardware.

YMMV.