# How can I expose my fan speed, cpu temp, etc to WMI and/or SNMP?

Tags: wmi, snmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collect temperature and fan speed with munin from Windows 7 PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/152154/collect-temperature-and-fan-speed-with-munin-from-windows-7-pc)

How can I expose my fan speed, cpu temp, etc to WMI and/or SNMP?

Free solutions are preferred.

On Windows XP/7.

Comment: duplicate @ http://superuser.com/q/152154/8228

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your drivers and what motherboard you have.  But this is quite possible.  For example, Asus exposes methods with their drivers.